# Quebra automática em menu com ícone e texto alinhados

Tags: css, html5, css3, sass

Estou fazendo um menu com `ul` e `li` onde dentro das minhas `li` tem um a com um `span` para o ícone e um `span` para o texto do item do menu. Atualmente quando ele chega em uma resolução xxx ele quebra os itens. Eu gostaria que quando fosse acontecer a quebra, o ícone ficasse em cima da palavra ao invés do que acontece atualmente que é ao lado mas isso sem usar um `@media (max-width: 1100px)`. Abaixo o fonte do menu e uma imagem de como eu queria que ficasse quando houvesse a quebra.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#nav-root {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
#nav-root > li {
  display: table;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 1px solid #e2e7eb;
}
#nav-root > li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e7eb;
}
#nav-root > li > a {
  display: table-cell;
  color: #585858;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*&.menu-link-1350 .menu-icon {*/
}
#nav-root > li > a:hover {
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  background-color: #f1f5f8;
  color: #e23d80;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e23d80;
}
#nav-root > li > a .menu-icon {
  width: 27px;
  height: 18px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#nav-root > li > a .menu-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-803 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/KSiKHuq.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-804 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/KSiKHuq.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-805 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/dGZs3ZN.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-1185 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Gof729V.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-1344 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/wvKgGhL.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-1345 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/dGZs3ZN.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-806 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/CpJVydF.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav-root">
    <li class="menu-list-804">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Smartphones">
        <a class="menu-link-804" href="" itemprop="url" title="Smartphones">

            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Smartphones</span>

        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list-803">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Celulares">
        <a class="menu-link-803" href="" itemprop="url" title="Celulares">
            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Celulares</span>

        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list-1185">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Telefonia">
        <a class="menu-link-1185" href="" itemprop="url" title="Telefonia">
            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Telefonia</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list-805">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Smart Gadgets">
        <a class="menu-link-805" href="" itemprop="url" title="Smart Gadgets">

            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Smart Gadgets</span>

        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list-1344">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Informática">
        <a class="menu-link-1344" href="" itemprop="url" title="Informática">
            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Informática</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list-1345">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Hardware">
        <a class="menu-link-1345" href="" itemprop="url" title="Hardware">
            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Hardware</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list-806">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Acessórios">
        <a class="menu-link-806" href="" itemprop="url" title="Acessórios">
            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Acessórios</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Como eu gostaria que ficasse com a quebra automática:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual é o motivo de não usar o `@media `?

Comment: é que no projeto eu uso 4 resoluções para media fixa onde eu estendo de um arquivo base para todos os outros e tendo as resoluções nos media pré-definidos é 1020px, 800px, 520px, 380px e a quebra está ocorrendo antes do 1020px

Comment: somente com `CSS` acredito que você não vai conseguir. Acho que você terá que usar `JS`, você pode usar?

Comment: posso sim @MoisesGama

Comment: esqueci de te perguntar você tem `JQuery` no projeto? Ou será `JS` puro mesmo?

Comment: @MoisesGama tenho sim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor maneira de se fazer isso é utilizando `@media-queries`.

Não precisas necessariamente de seguir essas medidas padrões dos `@media-queries` que mencionas-te no teu comentário na tua pergunta, podes simplesmente criar uma nova `@media-query` para isso responsável por essa modificação:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
span.menu-icon {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block !important;
}
span.menu-text {
    display: block !important;
}
}
```

Aqui está um [**exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/src_code/kqd64wr4/). Arrasta a janela do resultado para poderes ver isto em ação.
Para o teu projeto, basta apenas modificar a resolução do `@media-query` do código acima para a resolução que queres que esta modificação ocorra.

## 2ª Opção - Utilizando jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  width = $(window).width();
  if( width < 768 ) {
    $('.menu-icon ').addClass('smallRes-menu-icon');
    $('.menu-text ').addClass('smallRes-menu-text');
  } else {
    $('.menu-icon ').removeClass('smallRes-menu-icon');
    $('.menu-text ').removeClass('smallRes-menu-text');
  }
});
```

```
.smallRes-menu-icon {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block !important;
}
.smallRes-menu-text {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Aqui tens um [**exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/src_code/kqd64wr4/1/) desta segunda opção.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui o efeito da imagem alterando apenas uma regra CSS (inclui aqui apenas o que modifiquei):

```
#nav-root > li > a .menu-icon {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#nav-root {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
#nav-root > li {
  display: table;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 1px solid #e2e7eb;
}
#nav-root > li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e7eb;
}
#nav-root > li > a {
  display: table-cell;
  color: #585858;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*&.menu-link-1350 .menu-icon {*/
}
#nav-root > li > a:hover {
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  background-color: #f1f5f8;
  color: #e23d80;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e23d80;
}
#nav-root > li > a .menu-icon {
  width: 27px;
  height: 18px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#nav-root > li > a .menu-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-803 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/KSiKHuq.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-804 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/KSiKHuq.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-805 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/dGZs3ZN.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-1185 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Gof729V.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-1344 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/wvKgGhL.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-1345 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/dGZs3ZN.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li > a.menu-link-806 .menu-icon {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/CpJVydF.png") center top no-repeat;
}
#nav-root > li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav-root">
    <li class="menu-list-804">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Smartphones">
        <a class="menu-link-804" href="" itemprop="url" title="Smartphones">

            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Smartphones</span>

        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list-803">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Celulares">
        <a class="menu-link-803" href="" itemprop="url" title="Celulares">
            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Celulares</span>

        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list-1185">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Telefonia">
        <a class="menu-link-1185" href="" itemprop="url" title="Telefonia">
            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Telefonia</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list-805">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Smart Gadgets">
        <a class="menu-link-805" href="" itemprop="url" title="Smart Gadgets">

            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Smart Gadgets</span>

        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list-1344">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Informática">
        <a class="menu-link-1344" href="" itemprop="url" title="Informática">
            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Informática</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list-1345">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Hardware">
        <a class="menu-link-1345" href="" itemprop="url" title="Hardware">
            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Hardware</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list-806">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Acessórios">
        <a class="menu-link-806" href="" itemprop="url" title="Acessórios">
            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
            <span class="menu-text" itemprop="name">Acessórios</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```